# Orbeon Dynamic Html Label is being duplicated

Tags: orbeon

I have created a dynamic HTML label. When is rendered by orbeon runner first it shows correctly but when I add a new item in a repeated grid inside it gets duplicated

The HTML label is like this:

```
<div class="form-table--head">
    <div class="content-left">
        <p class="property--title"></p><span class="property--qty">{$itCount} counted</span>
        <div class="box-info box-link-popup hidden-xs">
            <div class="box__popup" tabindex="-1">
                <p>Options:</p>
                <ul>
                    <li>Option 1.</li>
                    <li>Option 2.</li>
                    <li>Option 3.</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <p class="property--amount property--amount-xs">{$itSum} &euro;</p>
    </div>
    <div class="content-right">
        <p class="property--amount hidden-xs">{$itSum} &euro;</p>
        <div class="header-menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Do something</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Do something</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Do something</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the entire form source code: https://pastebin.com/P3VK4hKm

Here is the behaviour first time:
[image]

And here after add a new iteration:
[image]

I am using Orbeon 2018.2.3 PE

Comment: I can reproduce this with 2018.2.3, but not with the latest code, soon to be released as 2019.1. Do you think that you will be able to upgrade to 2019.1 once it is released, and would that solve your problem? ‑Alex

Comment: However, things are not perfect with 2019.1, as I found [this issue](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/4136) while looking into this. We'll make to take care of it before the 2019.1 release. ‑Alex

Comment: We are going to try to simplify the HTML code of the label. The issue is produced by something specific of our code? Maybe if we try to avoid that, we could maintain our client's desired functionality. When is the 2019.1 release due date? When it will be released we could try to upgrade it and see if it fixes our problem and maintains our complex form functionalities

Comment: I suspect that the but in 2018.2.3 is triggered by the structure of the form, rather than the HTML in the title, but I might be wrong, so you'll let me know what you find when simplifying the HTML in the title. And 2019.1 is planned to be released during the summer ‑Alex

Comment: We have tried to put the same HTML structure in title but without any dependent parameter to the form and the result is that the title is not duplicated. So it looks like that there is something wrong with the parameter update and the html refresh, hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for testing this. We'll most likely start by fixing [#4136](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/4136) for 2019.1, and hopefully you can upgrade to that version when it is released.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior you noticed is caused by a bug, which is fixed in Orbeon Forms in 2019.1. For reference, the issue is tracked as [#4136](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/4136).